# toggle boolean with if statement

Tags: typescript

I currently I have this code

```
if (this.showAllOnlineFriends === false) {
  this.showAllOnlineFriends = true;
} else {
  this.showAllOnlineFriends = false;
}
```

When you press a button, it will toggle a boolean on or off. Is there a more readable way to write this?

Comment: Generally for a good code review it is better to include more code in your question.

Comment: Things like these are often better to be idempotent. In other words it might be better have a show function and a hide function. No matter how many times you call show you always know that friends will be shown. And no matter how many times you call hide, you know friends will be hidden. For a toggle you keep flipping between states and you need to know current state before toggling to foresee the state after toggling. But then again you left us guessing what is your use case and so what is more suitable for you. And so I vote to close your question.

Answer (score 7):

Value flipping is traditionally just done with a negation:

```
this.showAllOnlineFriends = !this.showAllOnlineFriends
```

That is a common, good practice way to do it. It is highly recognizable and easy to understand